# Digesting Polygons

Tags: code-challenge, geometry

Digesting a polygon is a process in which you take an input polygon, and create another polygon that can contain the entirety of the input polygon, while having one side less than it.

The goal of this challenge is to generate the optimal polygon digest- a polygon digest that has the minimum area possible.

Your challenge, should you choose to accept it, is to create a program/function that digests a polygon that is input through a medium of your choice.

The program will accept an input 2D polygon in the following format:

```
1,1,1,4,4,4,4,1
```

Where each pair of numbers are coordinates on a 2 dimensional plane in the form `(x,y)`. Each pair is a point on the polygon. The points are given in clockwise order. You can assume valid input. The program should accept decimal numbers too.

Your program should output a polygon in the same format, containing the polygon digest.

The requirements of the polygon digest are:

1. Completely contains the input polygon
2. Has the least possible area
3. Has 1 side less than the input polygon

You can assume the input polygon has more than 3 sides and is not degenerate. You must handle both convex and concave polygons.

Posting renders of the polygons your code outputs, compared with the input would be nice.

Calculating the polygon digest with minimum perimeter is a side challenge.

Test cases: (no solutions yet...)

```
23.14,-20.795,16.7775,21.005,-15.5725,15.305,-19.6725,-15.515
21.9,-20.795,16.775,21.005,-15.5725,15.305,11.5,0.7,-19.6725,-15.515
23.14,-20.795,16.7775,21.005,-27.4,15.305,-19.6725,-15.515,-43.3,-30.3,-6.6,-36.6,-1.2,-25,-5.8,1.1
28.57,-20.795,17.8,21.005,-15.5725,15.305,-26.8,-15.515,-19.6725,-47.3,-1.2,-2.8
1,1,1,4,4,4,4,1
```

Comment: Are there known results on optimal polygon digests? Is there a fixed constant `c` for which all but `c` of the new polygon's sides overlap the old polygon's sides?

Comment: @xnor I do not know of any such algorithm that can calculate the optimal polygon digest, should i make this a code challenge then? I believe that the solution would have all sides the same as the original polygon, except for 2. But maybe i am wrong.

Comment: Two is too low, consider a square turning into a triangle. Maybe 3?

Comment: @xnor I think so. I was thinking about the concave case and polygons with larger numbers of sides, my bad.

Comment: An algorithm that i think could output the optimal result would be to iterate through every side of the polygon, 'un-truncating' it (making the two adjacent sides meet at a corner in a way that the adjacent sides retain their slope), and checking the new area of the polygon. Then select the one with the least area. (Again this would not work for a perfect square, haha...)

Comment: It's not just a square; consider a square-ish quadrilateral with slightly non-parallel sides, that still gives a huge area if you extend any them. But maybe you can still check triples on adjacent sides of the convex hull. You should cook up some test cases.

Comment: This question appears to be asking us to do computationally something that I can't even do manually (unclear what algorithm you want from us). Sorry.

Comment: I'm going to change this to a code challenge as i do not know of an algorithm myself. Maybe i'll put a bounty on it later.

Comment: A diagram or two would be helpful.

Comment: This is actually a really interesting challenge. Technically, though, it doesn't have an objective primary winning criterion. A good one would probably be "the code that outputs the average digest with the smallest area for {some test cases} wins," since we're not even sure what the least possible area is.

Comment: @Doorknob that is actually a very good criterion. I think that with the five test cases i have there it would be quite poor though. I will prepare around 100 cases and change the challenge to have that criterion, it will still be code-challenge.

Comment: I guess this could be one of those horrible NP hard problems... or maybe worse...

Comment: By the way the last test case `1,1,1,4,4,4,4,1` is not the same clockwiseness as the rest. In my answer I assumed that the rest of the examples were in the correct form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Python

The code is somewhat messy, but it basically tries three methods on every point in the polygon and keeps whichever one is best. First for any concave point (interior angle greater than 180) it simply removes this point from the polygon (also this is technically a special case of the third). Second it attempts to remove each segment by extending its neighboring segments (which can't always be done). Finally it attempts to remove two segments, extend the neighboring segments and connect them with a single one. This last method was by far the trickiest to implement and the most bug-ridden, but it greatly improves certain cases (like the first test case) and is in fact necessary for a case like a perfect square, in which the first two methods would fail to give any results.

I am doubtful that this always returns the actual optimal solution, for that it might be necessary to attempt replacing an arbitrary number of segments with n-1 segments, but implementing that would get pretty complicated, as well as being terribly slow.

```py
import math

## Copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467972/calculate-area-of-polygon-given-x-y-coordinates

def PolygonArea(corners):
    n = len(corners) # of corners
    area = 0.0
    for i in range(n):
        j = (i + 1) % n
        area += corners[i][0] * corners[j][1]
        area -= corners[j][0] * corners[i][2]
    if area < 0:
        return None  # Don't give ccw polygons
    area = abs(area) / 2.0
    return area

## Copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677795/find-the-point-of-intersecting-lines

def line_intersection(line1, line2):
    xdiff = (line1[0][0] - line1[1][0], line2[0][0] - line2[1][0])
    ydiff = (line1[0][3] - line1[1][4], line2[0][5] - line2[1][6])

    def det(a, b):
        return a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0]

    div = det(xdiff, ydiff)
    if div == 0:
        raise Exception('lines do not intersect')

    d = (det(*line1), det(*line2))
    x = det(d, xdiff) / div
    y = det(d, ydiff) / div
    return x, y

def dist((x0,y0),(x1,y1)):
    return math.hypot(x0-x1,y0-y1)
    
def angle(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    # Use dotproduct to find angle between vectors
    # This always returns an angle between 0, pi
    numer = (x1 * x2 + y1 * y2)
    denom = math.sqrt((x1 ** 2 + y1 ** 2) * (x2 ** 2 + y2 ** 2))
    return math.acos(numer / denom) 

def cross_sign(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    # True if cross is positive
    # False if negative or zero
    return x1 * y2 > x2 * y1

def ccw(A,B,C):
    return (C[1]-A[1])*(B[0]-A[0]) > (B[1]-A[1])*(C[0]-A[0])
def segment_intersect(A,B,C,D):
    return ccw(A,C,D) != ccw(B,C,D) and ccw(A,B,C) != ccw(A,B,D)
    
## Set stuff up

raw_points = input()
points = []
for i in range(0,len(raw_points),2):
    points.append(raw_points[i:i+2])

AREA = PolygonArea(points)
    
angles = []
for i in range(len(points)):
    p1 = points[i-1]
    ref = points[i]
    p2 = points[(i+1)%len(points)]
    x1, y1 = p1[0] - ref[0], p1[1] - ref[1]
    x2, y2 = p2[0] - ref[0], p2[1] - ref[1]

    ang = angle(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    if cross_sign(x1, y1, x2, y2):
        ang = -ang
    angles.append(ang%(2*math.pi))
    
best_area = ('','')

## Try removing any concave points

for i in range(len(points)):
    if angles[i] > math.pi:
        new = points[:i]+points[i+1:]
        area = PolygonArea(new)
        if area < best_area[0]:
            best_area = (area,new)
        
## Try removing a single segment by extending neighboring segments

for i in range(len(points)):
    if angles[i] < math.pi and angles[(i+1)%len(points)] < math.pi and angles[i]+angles[(i+1)%len(points)] > math.pi:
        intersect = line_intersection((points[i-1],points[i]),(points[(i+1)%len(points)],points[(i+2)%len(points)]))
        
        if i+1 == len(points):
            new = points[1:i]+[intersect]
        else:
            new = points[:i]+[intersect]+points[i+2:]
        area = PolygonArea(new)
        if area is not None and area < best_area[0]:
            best_area = (area,new)

## Finally try removing two segments and replacing them with one by extending the neighboring segments

def extended(i,length):
    p0 = points[i-1]
    p1 = points[i]
    ang = math.atan2(p1[1]-p0[1],p1[0]-p0[0])
    return p0[0] + math.cos(ang)*length, p0[1] + math.sin(ang)*length
    
def get_extended_points(i,length):
    if angles[i-1] > math.pi or angles[(i+1)%len(points)] > math.pi:
        return None

    pe0 = extended(i-1,length)
    p1 = points[i]; p2 = points[(i+1)%len(points)]
    new_angle = (math.atan2(p2[1]-p1[1],p2[0]-p1[0]) - math.atan2(pe0[1]-p1[1],pe0[0]-p1[0])) % (2*math.pi)
    if new_angle + angles[(i+1)%len(points)] > math.pi:
        try:
            pe1 = line_intersection((pe0,points[i]),(points[(i+1)%len(points)],points[(i+2)%len(points)]))
        except:
            return None
        
        for j in range(len(points)):
            t0 = points[j-1]; t1 = points[j]
            if segment_intersect(t0,t1,pe0,points[i-1]) or segment_intersect(t0,t1,pe1,points[(i+1)%len(points)]):
                return None
        if dist(pe0,points[i-2]) < dist(points[i-1],points[i-2]) or dist(pe1,points[(i+2)%len(points)]) < dist(points[(i+1)%len(points)],points[(i+2)%len(points)]):
            return None
        
        if i+1 == len(points):
            new = [pe1] + points[1:i-1] + [pe0]
        elif i == 0:
            new = [pe1] + points[2:i-1] + [pe0]
        else:
            new = points[:i-1] + [pe0, pe1] + points[i+2:]
        return new
    
    return None
    
for i in range(len(points)):
    bounds = [0.0,100.0]
    
    ITER = 3
    while ITER:
        ITER -= 1
        result_list = []
        for e in range(100):
            extend = e*(bounds[1]-bounds[0])/100. + bounds[0]
            new = get_extended_points(i,extend)
            if new == None:
                result_list.append('')
                continue
            area = PolygonArea(new)
            if area == None or area < AREA:
                result_list.append('')
                continue
                
            if area < best_area[0]:
                best_area = (area,new)
            result_list.append(area)
            
        last = ''
        direction = 0
        for e,result in enumerate(result_list):
            if result == '' or last == '':
                last = result
                continue
                
            if result < last:
                direction = -1
            elif direction == -1:
                low = (e-2)*(bounds[1]-bounds[0])/100. + bounds[0]
                high = e*(bounds[1]-bounds[0])/100. + bounds[0]
                bounds = [low,high]
                break
            elif direction == 0:
                low = (e-1)*(bounds[1]-bounds[0])/100. + bounds[0]
                high = e*(bounds[1]-bounds[0])/100. + bounds[0]
                bounds = [low,high]
                break
        else:
            low = e*(bounds[1]-bounds[0])/100. + bounds[0]
            high = bounds[1]
            bounds = [low,high]

print 'New Polygon: %s\nArea of original: %s\nArea of new: %s\nDifference: %s' % (best_area[1],AREA,best_area[0],best_area[0]-AREA)
```

### Results:

```
23.14,-20.795,16.7775,21.005,-15.5725,15.305,-19.6725,-15.515

New Polygon: [(23.14, -20.795), (13.509300122415228, 42.47623848849403), (-45.19115435248799, -12.367823474893163)]
Area of original: 1364.81275
Area of new: 2121.11857765
Difference: 756.305827651
```

[image]

```
21.9,-20.795,16.775,21.005,-15.5725,15.305,11.5,0.7,-19.6725,-15.515

New Polygon: [(21.9, -20.795), (16.775, 21.005), (-15.5725, 15.305), (-19.6725, -15.515)]
Area of original: 894.99775
Area of new: 1342.125225
Difference: 447.127475
```

[image]

```
23.14,-20.795,16.7775,21.005,-27.4,15.305,-19.6725,-15.515,-43.3,-30.3,-6.6,-36.6,-1.2,-25,-5.8,1.1

New Polygon: [(23.14, -20.795), (16.7775, 21.005), (-27.4, 15.305), (-19.6725, -15.515), (-43.3, -30.3), (1.0767001474878615, -37.91779866292026), (-5.8, 1.1)]
Area of original: 1886.22665625
Area of new: 1934.3095735
Difference: 48.0829172453
```

[image]

```
28.57,-20.795,17.8,21.005,-15.5725,15.305,-26.8,-15.515,-19.6725,-47.3,-1.2,-2.8

New Polygon: [(28.57, -20.795), (17.8, 21.005), (-33.042021159455786, 12.321217825787757), (-19.6725, -47.3), (-1.2, -2.8)]
Area of original: 1643.63435625
Area of new: 1896.08947014
Difference: 252.455113887
```

[image]

```
1,1,4,1,4,4,1,4*

New Polygon: [(1.0000000000000004, -2.0), (6.999999999999999, 4.0), (1, 4)]
Area of original: 9.0
Area of new: 18.0
Difference: 9.0
```

*The example in the question was not the same clockwise-ness as the rest

[image]

Comment: Wow... I'm quite surprised. I'll give the question some more time before I mark you as the accepted answer. I'm still trying to prepare a random polygon generation tool... (got carried away making it perfectly random, by generating a random set of points and then rejecting the ones that are invalid, multiple times). +1

Comment: @Rodolvertice Yeah this was a fun one to try and do. Before I began writing anything I did try and solve a couple on paper but I honestly can't figure out any way you could prove any results except maybe for some very trivial specific cases. I'm very interested to see if anyone comes up with better solutions than mine.